# Elasticsearch bulk update query?

Tags: elasticsearch

After [reading this article here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update-by-query.html) i can't manage to translate the following SQL to elastic dsl:

```
UPDATE myIndex
set field1 = staticValue1, field2 = staticValue2
Where {
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "exists": {
                "field": "cnpj_estabelecimento"
            }}}}}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with the [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html), you have two parts:

- Query. What elements will be updated.
- Script. What changes will be done.

For the script part, you will have to play a little with [Painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-painless.html). Don't trust the name: Learning Painless is Painful (at the beginning).

Now, for your particular case, the thing you want to do, should look like this:

```
  POST /myIndex
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not" : {
        "exists" : {
          {
            "field": "cnpj_estabelecimento"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "script" : {
      "inline" : "ctx._source.field1= 'staticValue1'; ctx._source.field2= staticValue2;", 
      "lang"   : "painless"
      }
  }
```

Note than when you call the Update By Query API you do it via POST, not UPDATE.

Hope this is helpful! :D